# Service Method is is not called in Controller class

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

**Here is my controller Class**

```
  package com.kalam.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.kalam.daoimpl.EmployeeDaoImpl;
import com.kalam.model.Employee;
import com.kalam.service.EmployeeService;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class KalamController {

@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping("/kalam")
    public String showMessage(ModelMap map) {

        map.put("dollar", "50 US $");
        return "KalamWorld";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/insertData",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void InserData() {

        Employee emp= new Employee();
        emp.setEmpID(11);
        emp.setEmpName("On Target");
        emp.setEmpSalary(20000);
        emp.setAddress("Mumbai");



    ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("hibernate-cfg.xml"); // Line 1
    EmployeeDaoImpl dao= (EmployeeDaoImpl)context.getBean("employeeService"); // Line 2
    dao.addEmployee(emp);  // Line 3


    employeeService.addEmployee(emp);  // Line 4
    } 

}
```

**EmployeeDaoImpl class**

```
package com.kalam.daoimpl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.kalam.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.kalam.model.Employee;

@Repository("employeeDao")
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }



    public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(emp);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }



    public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) {
         Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(emp);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

    }



    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp, int id) {
         Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          session.beginTransaction();
            Employee employee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, new Integer(id));
            if(null != employee){
                session.delete(emp);
                                }
       session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

**EmployeeServiceImpl Code**

```
package com.kalam.serviceimpl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.kalam.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.kalam.daoimpl.EmployeeDaoImpl;
import com.kalam.model.Employee;
import com.kalam.service.EmployeeService;

@Service("employeeService")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS,rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{


    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
        employeeDao.addEmployee(emp);

    }

    public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp, int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**And finally hibernate-cfg.xml file**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<!-- Activate Spring annotation support -->
<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:annotation-driven /> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.serviceimpl"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.daoimpl"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.model"/>

<!-- DataSource configurationt -->
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kalamdb"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>  
    </bean>  

   <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
        </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>




 <bean id="employeeService" class="com.kalam.daoimpl.EmployeeDaoImpl">    
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />
 </bean>  



     <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />
       </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />



    </beans>
```

**If i comment the Line 4 code and @Autowired EmployeeService employeeService code and use Line 1 to line 3 code then it works fine and value is inserted. But when i uncomment @Autowired EmployeeService employeeService and Line 4(plus commenting Line Code of Line 1 to Line 3)  i'm getting following errors.**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kalamController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kalam.service.EmployeeService com.kalam.controller.KalamController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5633)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1694)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1684)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kalam.service.EmployeeService com.kalam.controller.KalamController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 24 more
```

**Please help me to resolve the errors. Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing annotations and xml config which in itself isn't bad thing but is resulting in overwriting one of your beans because of the confusion. In you xml you are defining the below;

```
<bean id="employeeService" class="com.kalam.daoimpl.EmployeeDaoImpl">    
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

This doesn't make sense to me as you are declaring dao bean with service name. perhaps you meant `employeeDao` as bean id?

Anyway the fix in my view is for you to clean up you config by either streamlining to either java config or in xml. and if you insist on using both than change your xml to following;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
   <!-- Activate Spring annotation support -->
   <context:annotation-config />
   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.controller,com.kalam.serviceimpl,com.kalam.daoimpl,com.kalam.model" />

   <!-- DataSource configurationt -->
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kalamdb" />
      <property name="username" value="root" />
      <property name="password" value="root" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="mappingResources">
         <list>
            <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>
         </list>
      </property>
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </bean>
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

and then add `@Autowired` to the `Sessionfactory` in `EmployeeDaoImpl` as below;

```
@Repository("employeeDao")
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   // Your other methods ...

}
```

This will ensure that the session factory is correctly injected in the dao and then dao in service and service in controller.